# GestureListenerManagerImpl is null make webview crash

Tags: android

Here is my stacktrace

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.chromium.content.browser.GestureListenerManagerImpl.hasPotentiallyActiveFling()' on a null object reference

    1 org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCoreImpl.isScrollInProgress(Unknown Source)
    2 org.chromium.tencent.TencentAwContent.onTopControlsShownHeight(Unknown Source)
    3 org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.nativeOnVSync(Native Method)
    4 org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.a(Unknown Source)
    5 org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid$1.onVSync(Unknown Source)
    6 org.chromium.ui.VSyncMonitor.a(Unknown Source
    7 org.chromium.ui.VSyncMonitor.a(Unknown Source)
    8 org.chromium.ui.VSyncMonitor$1.doFrame(Unknown Source)
    9 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:924)
    10 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
    11 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:664)
    12 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
    13 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
    14 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    15 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    16 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    17 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    18 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    19 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: post code for review

Comment: You need to provide a snippet of the code, [mcve] to get better help. please read [ask] for more information about asking good questions.